# PHP explode function give me a string that is not readable in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a string (`$string`)
from which I extract the `username` for querying  mysql database.
I am using the php `explode` function like the code below.

( `$number` is the total number of `id` in the string).

For each loop I get the `username` of Mysql database but 
the problem is that my query doesn't accept it.

For example, I get `Marta`  (shown on my display from `echo $usercut`) but the `$query` doesn't work and I don't get the 
`echo $row['email'];`.

The funny thing is that if I change `$usercut`
typing the string "Marta" 
`$usercut= "Marta";` it works!!!!!! and I get the `echo $row['email'];....` It is something that makes me mad...
Does someone know if the php `explode` function add some hidden character to the string?

```
<?php



$string = "<tr id='0r'>Marta</tr0r><tr id='1r'>Paolo</tr1r><tr id='2r'>Carlo</tr2r><tr id='3r'>Esther</tr3r><tr id='4r'>Franceso</tr4r><tr id='5r'>Charles</tr5r>";

str_replace("id=","id=",$string,$number);

for($i=0; $i<= $number; $i++)
{

     $start = "<tr id='".$i."r'>";
     $end = "<\/tr".$i."r>";
     $startHadCut = explode($start, $string) ;
     $endHadCut = explode($end,$startHadCut[1]);    

    echo   $usercut = $endHadCut [0];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `Database` WHERE username = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $usercut)."' LIMIT 1";   
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, $query));

        echo $row['email'];
}

?>
```

Comment: When I run your for loop it doesn't return what you're expecting. I am not getting a clean name on each loop with `echo   $usercut = $endHadCut [0];`

Comment: When all you know is `explode`, every string might potentially become dynamite.

Comment: I didn't write the code to get  $number. str_replace("id=","id=",$string,$number);// number of contacts

Comment: What is `</tr0r>`? Your string looks almost like HTML, except that makes it invalid -- it should just be `</tr>`

Comment: Also, use prepared queries, don't build your query using concatenations.

Comment: I agree with Barmer about not using explode for this. But your code should work as posted, if you remove the backslash from `$end`. There's no need to escape the slash.

Comment: I LOVE YOU jh1711!!!!! it was that backslash!!!!! THANKSSSSSS

Comment: Additionally, if you output something to the browser, remember to use `HTMLEntities()` or print it as plain text. Otherwise you'll get `Marta</tr0r>`, and the browser will show you `Marta` - and you won't immediately see why "Marta" is not in the database. Marta is; `Marta</tr0r>` isn't.

Comment: If you have control of the HTML here, you should rewrite. You then could use a parser and this whole process is much easier.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, you guys are amazing!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `explode()` you can get results more cleanly using some regex to do what you want, because `explode()` might not return what you expect.

Here is the regex I used, with [look aheads and look behinds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to get the text between the tags.

```
(?<=\'>)(.*?)(?=<\/tr)
```

Notice that I did not have to identify which tag was used, only the part of the tag relevant to getting the text from between them.

Using `preg_match_all()` this returns the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Marta
            [1] => Paolo
            [2] => Carlo
            [3] => Esther
            [4] => Franceso
            [5] => Charles
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Marta
            [1] => Paolo
            [2] => Carlo
            [3] => Esther
            [4] => Franceso
            [5] => Charles
        )

)
```

Now I can select a matched array and loop through them for the result:

```
$string = "<tr id='0r'>Marta</tr0r><tr id='1r'>Paolo</tr1r><tr id='2r'>Carlo</tr2r><tr id='3r'>Esther</tr3r><tr id='4r'>Franceso</tr4r><tr id='5r'>Charles</tr5r>";
$pattern = '/(?<=\'>)(.*?)(?=<\/tr)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $user) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Database` WHERE username = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $user)."' LIMIT 1";   
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, $query));
    echo $row['email'];
}
```

### WARNING

Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Thanks to everyone, you guys are amazing!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match_all()` to match the pattern in your data, rather than `explode()`.

```
preg_match_all("#<tr id='(\d+)'>(.*)</tr\\1>#", $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches[2] as $usercut) {
    ...
}
```